# extract token from http request header using GenericHttpCredentials

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am trying to extract the token from the authorization header of my HTTP request. The authorization header has the form `Authorization: Token token=abcdefg123`. I would like to have the following function signature but when I tried the following code snippet, a compilation error is `Cannot resolve symbol Map. Cannot resolve method Map.unapply`. I am not sure why this is happening. Any help is appreciated.

```
def extractToken(request: HttpRequest): Option[String] = {
  for {
    Authorization(GenericHttpCredentials("Token", "", Map("token"->token))) 
       <- request.header[Authorization]
  } yield token
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a working function,

```
private def extractToken(request: HttpRequest): Option[String] = {
  for {
    Authorization(GenericHttpCredentials("Token", "", params)) <- request.header[Authorization]
    token <- params.get("token")
  } yield token
}
```